# Calculating uv texture coords for a procedurally generated circle mesh

Tags: c#, mesh, texture-mapping, procedural-generation

I am trying to calculate the uv's for a mesh I generate in code. It's a very simple circle (2d)

[image]

and I want to texture it like follows

[image]

and using this code for the uvs

```
uvs[i] = new Vector2((verts[i].x+radius)/(radius), (verts[i].y+radius)/(2*radius));
```

and the center vertex is (0.5f,0.5f)

but I am getting a distorted image. (EDIT PHOTO after help from answer but still stretched)

[image]

could anyone help here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

Lets assume that the coordinates of the center vertex are (centerX, centerY)

```
uvs[i] = new Vector2(0.5f +(verts[i].x-centerX)/(2*radius), 
                             0.5f + (verts[i].y-centerY)/(2*radius));
```

Comment: Thank you, i didnt put the center parts in because the vertices are in local space and the center coord is (0,0) but it helped a lot. I have edited the photo.

There is still some stretching though

Comment: It looks that vertical coordinates are fine, just horizontal are wrong.
As I can remember, UVs u and v should be from range 0.0 - 1.0
Your recent image suggests that your u is more like from -0.5 to 1.5, are you sure you did not forget to divide by (2*radius)? 
(as in your original code the x-coord was divided just by radius)

Comment: How can we perform a similar procedure for an arbitrary planar shape?
Assume a 2d polygon, except the distance of the vertices to the center of the polygon is not the same.

Comment: @AramAzhari
You just need to scale and translate vertex coordinates into range [0.0 - 1.0]. This way you will get texture coordinates.

You need to calculate the WIDTH (max x delta) and HEIGHT (max y delta) of your polygon. You also need the coordinates of the center of your polygon: centerX and centerY.
Then for each vertex (x,y) you calculate its texture coordinates (u,v) in this way:
`u = 0.5f + (x - centerX)/WIDTH;`
`v = 0.5f + (y - centerY)/HEIGHT;`

So for vertices: (-2, 4) (6, 1) (4, 7)

WIDTH=8, HEIGHT=6, centerX=2, centerY=4

Texture coords: (0.0, 0.5) (1.0, 0.0) (0.75, 1.0)

Comment: @andrew_m I tried and it doesn't give what I want. I tried to explain my problem better [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397115/calculating-uv-texture-coords-for-a-procedurally-generated-polygon)