# Calculating uv texture coords for a procedurally generated polygon

Tags: uv-mapping, convex-polygon

I have a shape like this:

[image: Original vertices]

and the coordinates of the points are available (Vertices have x and y components)

My texture is:

[image: UV]

A simple planar UV mapping gives me:

[image: Unwanted UV mapping]

and what I desire is:

[image: Correct UV mapping]

How to calculate vertex positions to get the desired mapping? 
Note that this is a math problem.

Also, I can tolerate stretching, as long as the vertices fall on the grassy side.